# How to get dynamic (run-time) function resolution?

Tags: c++, c++20

How can I get the correct version of `isstronglyconvex` to be called based on the argument type in the code below:

```
#include <cassert> 
#include <iostream>

struct Loss{};

struct SupervisedLoss : public Loss {};

constexpr bool isstronglyconvex(const SupervisedLoss&) {
    return false;
}

struct TstStronglyConvexLoss : SupervisedLoss {};

constexpr bool isstronglyconvex(const TstStronglyConvexLoss&) {
    return true;
}

bool isstrictlyconvex(const SupervisedLoss& loss) {
    return isstronglyconvex(loss);
}

int main() {
    struct dl : TstStronglyConvexLoss {};
    struct sl : SupervisedLoss {};
    std::cout << isstrictlyconvex(TstStronglyConvexLoss()) << '\n';
    std::cout << isstrictlyconvex(SupervisedLoss()) << '\n';
    // assert(isstrictlyconvex(TstStronglyConvexLoss()) != (isstrictlyconvex(SupervisedLoss())));
}
```

As you can see from [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ex4xjrMv3), in both cases the `SupervisedLoss` version is called.

Comment: You seem to be using inheritance without any virtual functions. If this is the case, please bear in mind that this is not how inheritance is supposed to be used, and that your design is probably suboptimal. `isstrictlyconvex` probably should be a virtual function in `Loss`.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit OK this is interesting, is this what is stopping me from using polymorphism properly? Or at least the way I have it in my mind?

Comment: Inheritance-based polymorphism in C++ only works with virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a strongly typed language. You can pass `isstrictlyconvex()` any type that is derived from
`SupervisedLoss`, but `isstrictlyconvex()` only knows about `SupervisedLoss` since that is the static type of the parameter at compile time. So it ends up calling the overload of `isstronglyconvex()` that takes a `SupervisedLoss`, as that is an exact match.

Some ways you can accomplish what you want are to either:

- overload `isstrictlyconvex()` for each type, like you did for `isstronglyconvex()`:

```
bool isstrictlyconvex(const SupervisedLoss& loss) {
    return isstronglyconvex(loss);
}

bool isstrictlyconvex(const TstStronglyConvexLoss& loss) {
    return isstronglyconvex(loss);
}
```

- make `isstrictlyconvex()` use a template for its input parameter:

```
template <typename LossType>
bool isstrictlyconvex(const LossType& loss) {
    return isstronglyconvex(loss);
}
```

- have `isstrictlyconvex()` use `dynamic_cast` to figure out which overload of `isstronglyconvex()` to call at runtime. That requires adding a `virtual` method to `SupervisedLoss`, such as a virtual destructor (which you should have anyway):

```
struct Loss {
    virtual ~Loss() = default;
};

struct SupervisedLoss : Loss {};

...

struct TstStronglyConvexLoss : SupervisedLoss {};

...

bool isstrictlyconvex(const SupervisedLoss& loss) {
    const TstStronglyConvexLoss *strongLoss = dynamic_cast<const TstStronglyConvexLoss*>(&loss);
    if (strongLoss) {
        return isstronglyconvex(*strongLoss);
    }
    return isstronglyconvex(loss);
}
```

Comment: Having in mind that there are multiple loss types, and multiple functions for each. For your first solution it would mean that I would have to duplicate multiple functions times how many loss types exist, which is not very extensible if I want to add more loss types or loss properties later on. 
For the second one I need to duplicate each function once. I could live with this I guess.
The last one if I get it correctly needs a `dynamic_cast` for each loss type? Which would again make my code very hard to maintain.

Comment: @dearn44 then you probably need to rethink your design. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Depending on what you need, using dynamic dispatch (ie, virtual methods) at runtime may be more appropriate.

Comment: Yes, most probably my design is not good. I want to translate this [https://github.com/JuliaML/LossFunctions.jl] to C++. So a bunch of different loss types inheriting from a number of more basic loss types, and a number of properties for each loss type. It has proven a good exercise in learning so far.